# Create MongoDB database from terminal (without shell)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, terminal

I have a specific use case and I am looking for a way to create a database and collection using only the terminal, without using Mongo shell or Mongo Compass GUI.

The idea is to create the db and collection from the terminal before using `mongoimport`, like:

```
# Create database `company-example` and collection `employees` from the terminal
# ...
# ...
    
# Import the data to the collection
mongoimport --db=company-example --collection=employees --file=employees.json --jsonArray
```

I could create a npm package and run it with with Node from the terminal, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way?

Comment: You can execute a JS file with database and collection create commands _without_ physically logging into _mongo_ shell: [Write Scripts for mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/index.html#execute-a-javascript-file).

Comment: _"The idea is to use it before importing data..."_ - use it in what way?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, that was a typo... The idea is to create the db and collection before using `mongoimport`.... I updated the question

Comment: The import will create the database and the collection (which were not existing before) _ and_ load the data from the JSON. Why do you need to create a database and an empty collection before running the import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "clone" a database and an empty collection *from* a predefined database and collection (for the purpose of creating a new database with an empty collection). This is based upon another post by the author: [clone collection in mongoDB in the same db](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259827/clone-collection-in-mongodb-in-the-same-db).

First, create a database called as a `dummyDB`, and an empty collection called `testColl`. This is used to create/clone a database with one collection that is empty.

This command from terminal will create a clone:

```
mongodump --archive --db=dummyDB --collection=testColl | mongorestore --archive --nsFrom="dummyDB.*" --nsTo="examples.*"
```

The cloned database is `examples` and the collection with no documents `testColl`.

This process is useful in case you are creating the clones again and again.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to share this prasad_!

Comment: I am looking for a solution that my students can run during their first exercise with Mongo, meaning that they don't have any predefined db or collection, but rather need to run a code snippet that will create it for them, "fuss free".

Answer (score 1):

I assume that for some reason you would like to have DB and collection created prior to import.

1. create a script for example employees.js, with content:

`db.createCollection("employees", {collation:{locale:"en", strength:2}});`

2. start command from the terminal:

   `mongo company-example employees.js`

Please notice the first parameter of `mongo` command is DB name and the second is your script.
If DB does not exist it will be created automatically.